# How to do Video Trimmer in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I want to do a video trimmer in reactjs. I have searched and I got the package

Package name: **npm i react-video-trimmer**

Here is the example of this package,

**Example code:**

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactVideoTrimmer from "react-video-trimmer";
import "react-video-trimmer/dist/style.css";
 
const Trimmer = () => {
  const handleVideoEncode = React.useCallback(result => {
    console.log("Encoding Result:", result);
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <ReactVideoTrimmer
        onVideoEncode={handleVideoEncode}
        timeRange={{ start: 10, end: 100 }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

But, I don't know how to feed the video URL which I have to trim and I'm not clear about how this package is working.

So, please tell me how this package is working. And, Is there any alternative way to create a video trimer in Reactjs?